# Powershell function for modifying the ContentType of an object in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I'm trying to write a function in Powershell that sets blobs in a specific container to a certain type, as they are always written with the type `application/octet-stream` which causes issues with downstream applications. I have written the below function but  it returns the error `'ContentType' is a ReadOnly property.`

I was wondering if there was any way around this? I know the property can be set manually in Azure Storage Explorer, however this is a daily task.

Function:

```
 Function Set-ContentType {

    Param (
        [string]$accountName,
        [string]$accessKey,
        [string]$storageContainer
    )

    # Connect to blob storage and get blobs
    $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accessKey
    $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $storageContainer -Context $context -Blob $fileMask

    foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
        if ($blob.ContentType -eq $genericMIME) {
            $blob.ContentType = $targetMIME
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would believe that you should track down the uploading application and have them introduce a change, that sets this correctly. Have you tried downloading / uploading the files with the new content type?

Comment: This link might help you: https://liftcodeplay.com/2017/11/28/how-to-fix-azure-storage-blob-content-types/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my own issue by writing an alternative upload script that defines the ContentType at the time of writing the blob:

```
 Function UploadFile {

    Param (
        [string]$accountName,
        [string]$accessKey
    )

    $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accessKey

    $files = Get-ChildItem $workingDir -Filter $fileMask

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $file.FullName -Container $container -Properties @{"ContentType" = "$targetMIME"} -Context $context -Force
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on the link from the comments, please give this solution a try.

```
 Function Set-ContentType {

    Param (
        [string]$accountName,
        [string]$accessKey,
        [string]$storageContainer
    )

    # Connect to blob storage and get blobs
    $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accessKey
    $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $storageContainer -Context $context -Blob $fileMask

    foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
        if ($blob.ContentType -eq $genericMIME) {
            $blob.Properties.ContentType = $targetMIME
            $blob.SetProperties()
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This does not work. The API exposed by `Get-AzureStorageBlob` does not allow writing the content type property.

Comment: @supertopi Could you share the link for the API, so I can have a look at it?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.common.storage.resourcemodel.azurestorageblob.contenttype?view=azurerm-ps#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Commands_Common_Storage_ResourceModel_AzureStorageBlob_ContentType) you go.